# Solr No "Content" Field in Collection after Indexing PDFs/DOCs

Tags: solr

I have a collection of thousands of documents/pdfs and there are a lot of fields like: url, title, date...etc. But there is no content field, which is something that seems like it must exist in order for you to be to able to search by keywords of the entire document, not just the title. I see some people saying that usually, the content field is generated automatically when you index.

How do I go about adding a content field that should contain all the text in the PDFs/DOCs? I am on Solr 6 so I know I need to use API to create a new field to work with managed-schema. But after that, how do I re-index my collection? And if I just name the new field "content", will Solr know that the "content" field should contain all the text in my PDFs/DOCs when it's reindexing?

Comment: You'll have to create the content field, then reindex. Reindexing is done the same was you originally indexed your data - that's _reindexing_. There is no built-in way to do that, you just do the same process again.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for replying! so just to clarify, by adding a content field and then reindexing, solr will automatically know that the content field should contain the contents of the docs/pdfs?

Comment: It should. Try it with a single document before you reindex everything :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a "content" field did not work! Instead, I set stored=true for my `_text_` field and everything worked.